# Combining multiple audio files in Python (with delay)

Tags: audio

I'm looking to combine a range of different audio files (mp3) in Python. One of the requirements is that I need to be able to specify a delay at the end of each file. To illustrate, something like:

[file1.mp3--------3 seconds----------][delay---------2 seconds--------][file2.mp3]-------------4 seconds][delay---------2 seconds][file3.mp3----------3 seconds---------]

Does anyone here know of any mp3 libraries that can accomplish this? Python isn't really a necessity here. If it'll be easier in another language, that'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) can do this, given the right arguments. No real need to use a library.

Comment: There are other things I'd need to do as well (such as parsing, renaming files, dynamically altering the delay based on the length of the audio file, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To combine wav or aiff files, you can do something like this: (inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-file-using-python))

```
import aifc

def concatenate(*items):
    data = []

    for item in items:
        f = aifc.open(item, 'rb')
        data.append([f.getparams(), f.readframes(f.getnframes())])
        f.close()

    output = aifc.open('output.aif', 'wb')
    output.setparams(data[0][0])

    for item in data:
        output.writeframes(item[1])

    output.close()
```

See the link for the wav format (it's pretty much the same, but with the wave library)

To add silence, I would just make a one second silent file using your favorite audio editor and then concatenate in the proper amount of silence.