# Linux and python: Combining multiple wave files to one wave file

Tags: python, linux, wave

I am looking for a way that I can combine multiple wave files into one wave file using python and run it on linux. I don't want to use any add on other than the default shell command line and default python modules. 
For example, if I have a.wav and b.wav. I want to create a c.wav which start with the content from a.wav then b.wav. 
I've found wave module, that I can open a wave file and write into a new file. Since i'm really new in this audio world. I still can't figure out how to do it. Below is my code

```
import struct, wave

waveFileA = wave.open('./a.wav', 'r')
waveFileB = wave.open('./b.wav', 'r')
waveFileC = wave.open('./c.wav', 'w')

lengthA = waveFileA.getnframes()
for i in range(0,lengthA):
    waveFileC.writeframes(waveFileA.readframes(1))

lengthB = waveFileB.getnframes()
for i in range(0,lengthB):
    waveFileC.writeframes(waveFileB.readframes(1))

waveFileA.close()
waveFileB.close()
waveFileC.close()
```

When i run this code, I got this error:

```
wave.Error: # channels not specified
```

Please can any one help me?

Comment: Please post the full traceback from it, on what line does it die?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the number of channels, sample width, and frame rate:

```
waveFileC.setnchannels(waveFileA.getnchannels())
waveFileC.setsampwidth(waveFileA.getsampwidth())
waveFileC.setframerate(waveFileA.getframerate())
```

If you want to handle a.wav and b.wav having different settings, you'll want to use something like [pysox](http://packages.python.org/pysox/) to convert them to the same settings, or for nchannels and sampwidth you may be able to tough through it yourself.

Comment: It looks like you have a key for this, thx. However, can you tell me a bit more for the case that a.wav and b.wav have different settings?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to call `n=waveFileA.getnchannels()` to find out how many channels the first input file uses, likewise for waveFileB, then you'll need to use `waveFileC.setnchannels(n)` to tell it how many channels to put in the outgoing file.  I don't know how it will handle input files with different numbers of channels...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I am looking for

[How to join two wav files using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-file-using-python)
(look for a thread by Tom 10)

It's in another thread. some one already solved this problem.