# Concatenate wav files using wave in python

Tags: python, audio, text-to-speech, wav, wave

I am trying to concatenate a list of wav files into a single continuous wav file. I have used the following snippet but the output is not correct, sounds almost like the files are on top of each other. `audio_files` is a list with .wav filenames that are playing as expected.

This is my current code:

```
outfile = "sounds.wav"

    data= []
    for wav_file in audio_files:
        w = wave.open(wav_file, 'rb')
        data.append( [w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())] )
        w.close()
    output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
    output.setparams(data[0][0])
    output.writeframes(data[0][1])
    output.writeframes(data[1][1])
    output.close()
```

Comment: how many file are there? this is only writing 2 of your wav's frame data to the ouptut file

Comment: the number can vary, usually less than 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you were using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python) as your reference. However, the code that you have taken only takes into account 2 wav files because that is what the original question had asked.

Although I am not if this will fix the problem of the sound being on top of each other, you should iterate through each item in your `data` list.

```
output = wave.open(outfile, 'wb')
output.setparams(data[0][0])
for params,frames in data:
    output.writeframes(frames)
output.close()
```

to ensure you are putting in the frames from each file you have.

One thing to keep in mind is that the params for your new wav files might be specific to each file and you might want to check that [`getparams()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getparams) is returning similar results for each file.