# Minimize delay between two sounds played using winsound.PlaySound

Tags: python

```
winsound.PlaySound('1.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
time.sleep(0.15)
winsound.PlaySound('1.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

`1.wav` is a sound file of length 01s

There is delay of more then a second between the two `winsound.PlaySound` calls, even if `time.sleep` is commented out. But if the parameter for `time.sleep` is increase for more then `1s` then my code runs as it should.

I need to bring the delay down to a `0.15s`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The winsound module seems to be unloved. It hasn't adapted to the Python 3 distinction between bytes and strings (http://bugs.python.org/issue11620), so it can't play a .wav file that is stored in memory.

You should probably move to a different audio module such as `pyaudio` https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Since the file is a short one. You should read the whole file into memory. If there is still a gap, you can join the file to itself with 0.15 s of silence in the middle and then play (that single file). Audio modules `wave`, `pydub`, `audioop` or `audiolab` can do the joining. [How to join two wav files using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python)