# how to concatenate all the audio (.wav )files in a folder using python?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to combine all the .wav files in a folder to singe large .wav please help

```
import subprocess
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in 
os.walk('/Users/user/Downloads/audio_files'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.WAV'):
        matches.append(root.replace('/Volumes/UNTITLED/',''))

folders = set(matches)
print(folders)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two wav files using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should use wave library from Python. Refer to the [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/read-and-write-wav-files-using-python-wave)

Also there are few [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python)

Comment: You can add as many files as you want. Refer to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900266/8477049).  While writing frames to output file, you can use for loop instead. Hope it helps!