# Combine two audio files in Python

Tags: python, audio, pycharm, append

I have two audiofiles:

```
'Users/x/Songs/1.mp4'
'Users/x/Songs/2.mp4'
```

I would like to join these to one audio file, where the two files play right after each other:

```
'Users/x/Songs/combined.mp4'
```

I'm using PyCharm on my Macbook to achieve this. Is there a way to do it?
I saw a solution is to use this code:

```
from glob import iglob
import shutil
import os

PATH = r'/Users/x/Songs'

destination = open('everything.mp4', 'wb')
for filename in iglob(os.path.join(PATH, '*.mp4')):
    shutil.copyfileobj(open(filename, 'rb'), destination)
destination.close()
```

But whenever I do this, I only get the last audio clip in the file called 'everything.mp4'.

Not sure what the code above does but found it as an answer to another question like the one I have.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused as to why you are using an mp4 (video) file for audio.

This [stack overflow post about joining wav files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python) might work in combination with the [python AudioConverter module](https://pypi.org/project/AudioConverter/)

It might look something like this:

```
import audioconverter
import audiolab, scipy
audioconvert convert wavfiledir/ outputdir/ --output-format .wav
a, fs, enc = audiolab.wavread('file1.wav')
b, fs, enc = audiolab.wavread('file2.wav')
c = scipy.vstack((a,b))
audiolab.wavwrite(c, 'file3.wav', fs, enc)
```

keep in mind you will need ffmpeg and with this solution you will lose
any video (not audio) if you have any.

A couple other possible solutions
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/merge+all+mp4+video+files+into+one+file+python

https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/join-all-mp4-with-python-and-ffmpeg/

https://gist.github.com/rohitrangan/3841212